# jQuery - Return colored hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return colored hyperlinks but it keeps failing.

So I've basically got a huge list of hyperlinks and some of them eventually get a color style of red. I'm trying through a button to list which ones are red at the current time. I keep getting back no results whatsoever.

HTML code:

```
<tr id="List" style="display: none;">
  <td>General
    <hr><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="0">#</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">First Name</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2" style="color: red;">Last Name</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3" style="color: red;">Country</a>
  </td>
</tr>

<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="options"/> Show Red Options!</label></p>
<div class="print"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#options').change(function () {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 4) {
    var color = $('a[data-column=' + i + ']').css('color');
      if (color === 'rgb(255,0,0)') {
        $('#options').attr($('.print').text("Data-Column ID: " + i));
      } else {
        $('#options').attr($('.print').text("Boo!"));
      }
    i++;
  }
});
```

I've tried both color "red" and the RGB one.

And here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ynph2wv/1/

Comment: You are doing this wrong and the hard way. The EASY way is to define a "class" and use CSS to set the style to red. You can VERY easily add or remove a class to any element with jQuery. It is very difficult to filter something by its style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. search for the proper color `rgb(255, 0, 0)` (note the spaces)
2. display the result correctly

```js
const print = $('.print');
print.html('');

$('#options').change(function() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 4) {
    var color = $('a[data-column=' + i + ']').css('color');
    if (color === 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
      print.append(`Data-Column ID: ${i}<br>`);
    } else {
      print.append(`ID ${i} Boo!<br>`);
    }
    i++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr id="List" style="display: none;">
  <td>General
    <hr><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="0">#</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">First Name</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2" style="color: red;">Last Name</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3" style="color: red;">Country</a>
  </td>
</tr>

<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="options"/> Show Red Options!</label></p>
<div class="print"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way. This is better approach and following way is loop around link with ***toggle-vis*** class.

```
$('#options').change(function () {
  var textToPrint = '';

  $('.toggle-vis').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
       textToPrint += $(this).text()+', '; 
    }

    $('.print').html(textToPrint.slice(0, -2));     // slice function is for removing the comma at the end.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do this. The idea is to use the attr method and see if it has a style setting a color

```js
$('#options').change(function () {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 4) {
    var element = $('a[data-column=' + i + ']');
    var style = element.attr('style')
    if(style) {
     if (style.indexOf('red') != -1) {
        $('.print').html($('.print').html() + " Data-Column ID: " + i + '<br>');
      } 
    } else {
        $('.print').html($('.print').html() + " Boo! ID: " + i + "<br>");
    }
    i++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr id="List" style="display: none;">
  <td>General
    <hr><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="0">#</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">First Name</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2" style="color: red;">Last Name</a> -
    <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3" style="color: red;">Country</a>
  </td>
</tr>


<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="options"/> Show Red Options!</label></p>
<div class="print"></div>
```